# How to use ColorPaletteResources in UWP?

Tags: xaml, win-universal-app, uwp-xaml, windows-10-universal

Could someone explain to me how to use ColorPaletteResources in UWP apps and AcrylicBrushes? I would like to create my own theme colors like backgrounds, textbox transparencies, buttons backgrounds, etc., but it's been a headache trying to learn how to use it and apply it since MS documentation doesn't show much information about it. I'll be happy also if someone knows about some courses or tutorials about how to create fluent design themes.

Comment: Based on this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/style/color#scoping-system-colors), it mentions some usages of ColorPaletteResources. You can create a ResourceDictionary, then place the ColorPaletteResources within the ThemeDictionaries and override the desired system colors. In addition, you can custom colors by using [Fluent XAML Theme Editor](https://github.com/microsoft/fluent-xaml-theme-editor) and then copy the resources to apply it.

Comment: I've tried that app but it doesn't work, it's stuck when you open it

Comment: This app requires Visual Studio 2017 Update 4 or higher and the Windows Software Development Kit (SDK) version 17763 or higher for Windows 10, do you meet this requirement? Or you can directly download this app from Microsoft Store to use it.

Comment: Ok, my Visual Studio was out of date and I didn't have the SDK installed so it might be that the problem

Comment: Yeap, you can first update your visual studio and try to use it again.